# send with curl rest api, multipart data with multiple content-type

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I used wiztools and set 3 parameters to rest api.

- appkey content-type text
- appsecret content-type text
- data content-type application/json

How can i define seperate content-types? 
You can look this wiztools request picture to understand best.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDVKG.jpg

When i use curl, response is ; The current request is not a multipart request

How can i create a request like wiztool's "multipart body" request with curl?

A new question; What is multipart mode in wiztool? If i set it to rfc6532 or strict, answer is true but if i set it "browser compatible" answer is "data not defined."

Now i am getting "data not defined" in curl result. How can i set this multipart mode to strict or rfc6532 in curl ?

Comment: Forgive me for the unhelpful comment, but what API is asking for an API key and secret using a multi-part document.  That is mind-blowingly strange.

Comment: I agree with you and I dont understand what they want. It is a big e-commerce system in my country this eats all of my time today. I read more and more & make too many tests.

Comment: Let me ask a different question.  If you can already send multi-part header with wiztool then why do you want to do it with curl?  What does curl allow you to do that wiztool can't?

Comment: @DarrelMiller This is rest api and i need to connect it always. I am creating php file, i must use curl. I am using wiztools for testing. It is working but curl is not. My real question is this. If i set multipart mode strict or rfc6532 like wiztool i think my php curl will work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the content-type header to

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x
```

The boundary value can be pretty much any value as long as it is unique.

Then you need to build a request body that looks like this...

```
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="appkey"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

{put key here}
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="appsecret"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

{put secret here}    
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="data"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{put json body here}
```

If you have trouble getting the body format correct, just use the Wiztool and send it via a [Runscope](http://www.runscope.com) URL and that will allow you to see exactly the body and header values that Wiztool is sending to the API.

Comment: I think about this. I made facebook application last year and used base64 etc. to send photo to album but it didnt work. I created picture to local and sent it with multi-part @file and it worked. But this way is complicated i can not create text files for all data=json-requests.

Comment: I tried to send file but it is not accaptable by api. Rejected.I dont know how can i fix this.

Comment: @maryblasso I understand now what you mean.  I thought you were using the command line cUrl tool, not the PHP library.